# WordPress website is not loading, probably the GCE VM instance in GCP is not working properly

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

My WordPress website hosted on my GCE VM instance is not loading for the past two days. It keeps trying and trying for a long time but it does not load. I'm not a professional, so I do not know what to do.

Please guide me.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask this. Stack Overflow is mainly meant for technical / programming questions... Maybe you're hitting a quota, or the disk is full... Trying to [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) into the VM and diagnosing it yourself is starter, where you can post your findings here. Regardless, more technical details are needed here and the question is too open ended at the moment. The best course of action for you would be to [contact GCP Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/) directly.

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances) is the documentation that provides general troubleshooting paths for GCE instances, have a look at it.